# cocos2D pushScene popScene

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm creating a scene,adding a main layer to the scene, and adding another layer to the main layer for the heads Up Display (HUD).  I then use the CCDirector pushScene method to call a second scene with a main/hud layer. my problem is after using the popScene to return to the first scene the HUD layer from the second scene is still actively receiving and handling touches.  I've tried using   self.isTouchEnabled = NO; in the HUD before I call popScene, but It has no effect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I figured it out, I needed to use the onExit and onEnter methods to disable and enable touch handling for each of the layers.  here is what the code looks like

```
-(void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];


    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate: self];
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
}


- (void) onExit {

    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate: self];
    [super onExit];
}
```

Comment: If you have to do that in a CCLayer class, you're leaking memory. This is not the fix, this is a workaround to a more serious underlying issue. Check if your CCLayer runs the dealloc method, I bet it doesn't.

Comment: My first few days of working with this problem I tried to dealloc the HUD layer, but it would always give me an assertion error when I ran the popScene routine because it was trying to pop a layer that didn't exist. any suggestion?